# Does not show comment list

Tags: comments

I can not see comments on my post. There is the code I use:

```
<?php if($comments) : ?>  
<ol class="post_comment_list clearfix">  
<?php foreach($comments as $comment) : ?>  
    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="clearfix">  
        <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>  
            <p>תגובה שלך מחכה לאישור</p>  
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 50 ); ?>  
        <div class="comment_content">
            <?php comment_text(); ?>  
            <p class="comment_meta">נשלח יל ידי: <?php comment_author_link(); ?></p>
            <?php edit_comment_link(); ?> 
        </div>
    </li>  
<?php endforeach; ?>  
</ol>
```

I admin I see 2 comments for this post, but on the page 0.
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you place this code?

Comment: And where and how variable `$comments` is filled?

Comment: This code is in comments.php file. How I must to fill $comments? with $comments = get_comments() ?